JavaScript await, try/catch and Microtask Queue
If I am not mistaken:
async function foo() {
  await bar();
  baz();
}

Corresponds to:
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(bar());
  }).then(() => {
    baz();
  });
}

So () => baz(); goes to Microtask Queue.
But what goes to Microtask Queue if we have try/catch block inside async function, for example:
async function foo() {
  try {
    await bar();
  } catch () {
    baz();
  }
  qux();
}


Do you have an immediate practical reason for caring about this?

await suspends execution of the function (it immediately returns a promise at that point).  When the promise is fulfilled and the fulfillment clears the microtask queue, then execution of the function continues where it left off.  Code isn't placed into the queue - that's not the right way to think of it.  Instead a promise fulfillment goes through the task queue in order to restart execution of the function at the appropriate point.

@jfriend00 "a promise fulfillment goes through the task queue" - no it doesn't. (Or: which task queue do you mean?) Why do you say that nothing is placed in the microtask queue? (Or: what is it if not code?)

Not every async/await code has a 1:1 corresponding .then() equivalent. Similarly, how do you think if (x) { await bar(); } qux(); is executed?

@Bergi I honestly don't know...

@AlexBor Do you understand how yield in a generator function can suspend and resume an execution?

@bergi - You're probably mostly arguing semantics here.  Until the promise is fulfilled, there's nothing in the queue related to that promise.  When it gets fulfilled, an event goes in the queue and when that fulfillment event gets to the front of the queue, it can then call all of it's fulfillment handlers (e.g. callbacks).  Semantically, I don't call that putting code into the queue.  I'm talking about the queue used for processing fulfilled promises - I believe it's referred to as the PromiseJobs queue and is not the main task queue.

@jfriend00 Ok then I misunderstood you, your first comment sounded like "when a promise is fulfilled, it scans through a task queue to find the functions to restart", the "goes through" is ambiguous. "an event goes in the queue [which] can then call all of it's fulfillment handlers" - afair the fulfillment places each fulfillment handler in the promisejobs queue, not just a single event. That's what I would call "putting code into the queue" (even though technically of course it is "a job to run the handler code").

@Bergi,so the promise callbacks aren't placed into the microtask queue - it is the event which will be created when the promise is resolved is placed into the microtask queue? The event is then responsible to execute the remaining code which was suspended by the await statement.

@NapoleonBonaparte The promise callbacks are placed into the microtask queue. The handler to resume the remaining code after the await statement is one of them.

@Bergi, one of the commenter said this: "When it gets fulfilled, an event goes in the queue and when that fulfillment event gets to the front of the queue, it can then call all of it's fulfillment handlers (e.g. callbacks)." Doesn't this suggest that there is an event that will be placed into the queue and execute all of its callback?

@NapoleonBonaparte And I pointed out that they are wrong on that bit. It is one job per handler.


But what goes to Microtask Queue if we have try/catch block inside async function, for example [...]

When the promise that is awaited (in this case the one returned by bar) is settled, a job will be queued in the microtask queue. When that job is dequeued and executed, it will restore the execution context of foo at the point where it was suspended.
We could visualise this with a comment in your code:
async function foo() {
  try {
    await bar();
    // <--- resume
  } catch () {
    baz();
  }
  qux();
}

If the promise rejected, the error with which it rejected will be thrown, and (as in a normal function), the catch block will kick in.
